# How can I count the characters in STDIN using perl without wc?

Tags: perl, loops, count, wc

I am attempting to write a script to count the number of lines, words, and characters input by the user in STDIN. Using the script below, I can accomplish this when a user inputs a file as a CLI, but when I attempt to use this code for STDIN, I end up with an infinite loop. What should I change to fix this?

```
print "Enter a string to be counted";
my $userInput = <STDIN>;
while ($userInput) {
        $lines++;
        $chars += length ($_);
        $words += scalar(split(/\s+/, $_));
}
printf ("%5d %5d %5d %10s", $lines, $words, $chars, $fileName);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your program is fine, expect that you need to *read* from the file handle in the `while` test. At present you are just reading one line from STDIN and repeatedly checking that it is *true* - i.e. not zero or `undef`.

Your code should look like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($lines, $chars, $words) = (0, 0, 0);

print "Enter a string to be counted";

while (<STDIN>) {
  ++$lines;
  $chars += length;
  $words += scalar split;
}

printf "%5d %5d %5d\n", $lines, $words, $chars;
```

Note that I have used just `length` instead of `length $_` as `$_` is the default parameter for the `length` operator. `$_` only really comes into its own if you use the defaults.

Similarly, the default parameters to `split` are `split ' ', $_` which is what you want in preference to `split /\s+/, $_` because the latter returns a zero-length initial field if there are any leading spaces in `$_`. The special value of a single literal space `' '` just extracts all the sequences of non-space characters, which is almost always what you want. Anything other than just a single space is converted to a regex pattern as normal.

Finally, I have used `++$lines` instead of `$lines++`. The latter is popular only because of the name of the language C++, and it is less common that the value returned by the expression needs to be the *original* value of the variable rather than the *new* one. Much more often the increment is used as a statement on its own, as here, when the returned value is irrelevant. If Perl didn't optimise it out (because the context is void and the return value is unused) the code would be doing unnecessary additional work to save the original value of the variable so that it can be returned after the increment. I also think `++$var` looks more like the imperative *"increment `$var`"* and improves the readability of the code.

Comment: Should newlines count as characters?  I guess either way could be correct.

Comment: @JohnC: I have just coded it to do the same as Craig's original program. Only he knows which is right

Answer (score 1):

Your input has to be within the loop. Else you are processing the same string over and over again.

Comment: Add your words to @JohnC's program and you have something greater than its parts :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you need?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Enter a string to be counted:\n";
my $lines = 0;
my $chars = 0;
my $words = 0;
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    $lines++;
    $chars += length ($_);
    $words += scalar(split(/\s+/, $_));
}
printf ("lines: %5d words: %5d chars: %5d\n", $lines, $words, $chars);
```

Comment: I think your program would be helped a lot by a little narrative